# RavenDB Map Reduce Function

Tags: c#, indexing, mapreduce, ravendb

I am trying to write a RavenDB Map Reduce function for an index to collate information from a bunch of DomainModels. I am unable to populate all the result fields but have spent a day or so on it and am missing something fundamental me thinks.

Here it is:

```
public class All_Groups : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<All_Groups.Result>
{
    public class Result
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string ChildId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string GroupType { get; set; }
        public int MemberCount { get; set; }
        public int ProjectCount { get; set; }
        public int TeamCount { get; set; }
        public int OrganisationCount { get; set; }
        public int ChildGroupCount { get; set; }
        public AppRoot AppRoot { get; set; }
        public Organisation Organisation { get; set; }
        public Team Team { get; set; }
        public Project Project { get; set; }
        public UserProject UserProject { get; set; }
    }

    public All_Groups()
    {
        AddMap<AppRoot>(appRoots => from appRoot in appRoots
                select new
                {
            Type = "group",
                    appRoot.Id,
                    ChildId = (string)null,
                    appRoot.Name,
                    GroupType = "approot",
                    MemberCount = 0,
                    ProjectCount = 0,
                    TeamCount = 0,
                    OrganisationCount = 0,
                    ChildGroupCount = 0
                });

        AddMap<Organisation>(organisations => from organisation in organisations
                select new
                {
            Type = "group",
                    organisation.Id,
                    ChildId = (string)null,
                    organisation.Name,
                    GroupType = "organisation",
                    MemberCount = 0,
                    ProjectCount = 0,
                    TeamCount = 0,
                    OrganisationCount = 1,
                    ChildGroupCount = 0
                });

        AddMap<Team>(teams => from team in teams
                select new
                {
            Type = "group",
                    team.Id,
                    ChildId = (string)null,
                    team.Name,
                    GroupType = "team",
                    MemberCount = 0,
                    ProjectCount = 0,
                    TeamCount = 1,
                    OrganisationCount = 0,
                    ChildGroupCount = 0
                });

        AddMap<Project>(projects => from project in projects
                select new
                {
            Type = "group",
                    project.Id,
                    ChildId = (string)null,
                    project.Name,
                    GroupType = "project",
                    MemberCount = 0,
                    ProjectCount = 1,
                    TeamCount = 0,
                    OrganisationCount = 0,
                    ChildGroupCount = 0
                });

        AddMap<UserProject>(userProjects => from userProject in userProjects
                select new
                {
            Type = "group",
                    userProject.Id,
                    ChildId = (string)null,
                    userProject.Name,
                    GroupType = "userproject",
                    MemberCount = 0,
                    ProjectCount = 0,
                    TeamCount = 0,
                    OrganisationCount = 0,
                    ChildGroupCount = 0
                });

        AddMap<GroupAssociation>(groupAssociations => from groupAssociation in groupAssociations
                select new
                {
            Type = "groupassociation",
                    Id = groupAssociation.ParentGroupId,
                    ChildId = groupAssociation.ChildGroupId,
                    Name = "n/a",
                    GroupType = "groupassociation",
                    MemberCount = 0,
                    ProjectCount = 0,
                    TeamCount = 0,
                    OrganisationCount = 0,
                    ChildGroupCount = 1
                });

        AddMap<Member>(members => from member in members
                select new
                {
            Type = "member",
                    member.Id,
                    ChildId = (string)null,
                    Name = "n/a",
                    GroupType = "member",
                    MemberCount = 1,
                    ProjectCount = 0,
                    TeamCount = 0,
                    OrganisationCount = 0,
                    ChildGroupCount = 0
                });

        Reduce = results => from result in results
                group result by result.Id
                into g
                select new
                {
            g.Where(x => x.Id == g.Key).First().Type,
            Id = g.Key,
            g.Where(x => x.Id == g.Key).First().ChildId,
            g.Where(x => x.Id == g.Key).First().Name,
            g.Where(x => x.Id == g.Key).First().GroupType,
            MemberCount = g.Where(x => x.Id == g.Key && x.Type == "member").Sum(x => x.MemberCount),
            ProjectCount = g.Where(x => x.GroupType == "project").Sum(x => x.ProjectCount),
            TeamCount = g.Where(x => x.GroupType == "team").Sum(x => x.TeamCount),
            OrganisationCount = g.Where(x => x.GroupType == "organisation").Sum(x => x.OrganisationCount),
            ChildGroupCount = g.Where(x => x.GroupType == "groupassociation" && x.Id == g.Key).Sum(x => x.ChildGroupCount)
                };

                TransformResults = (database, results) =>
                from result in results
                let appRoot = database.Load<AppRoot>(result.Id)
                let organisation = database.Load<Organisation>(result.Id)
                let team = database.Load<Team>(result.Id)
                let project = database.Load<Project>(result.Id)
                let userProject = database.Load<UserProject>(result.Id)
                select new
                {
                    result.Id,
                    result.Type,
                    result.Name,
                    result.GroupType,
                    AppRoot = appRoot,
                    Organisation = organisation,
                    Team = team,
                    Project = project,
                    UserProject = userProject,
                    result.MemberCount,
                    result.ProjectCount,
                    result.TeamCount,
                    result.OrganisationCount,
                    result.ChildGroupCount
                };


                Store(x => x.Type, FieldStorage.Yes);
                Store(x => x.Id, FieldStorage.Yes);
                Store(x => x.Name, FieldStorage.Yes);
                Store(x => x.GroupType, FieldStorage.Yes);
                Store(x => x.MemberCount, FieldStorage.Yes);
                Store(x => x.ProjectCount, FieldStorage.Yes);
                Store(x => x.TeamCount, FieldStorage.Yes);
                Store(x => x.OrganisationCount, FieldStorage.Yes);
                Store(x => x.ChildGroupCount, FieldStorage.Yes);
    }
}
```

Basically the problem seems to be that I am not getting any results for OrganisationCount and TeamCount although documents for them exist.

(If anyone would like the domain model diagram it's here: https://github.com/Bowerbird/bowerbird-web/blob/master/Docs/Model.vsd)

I've been tearing my hair out over this and it's almost there but I need some fresh eyes anyone??

Cheers,

Hamish.

Comment: I have an answer to this question but because : "Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 1 hour. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead." I need to wait an hour so don't bother answering in the mean time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's a bit simpler than I had up top. The problem I was trying to solve was:

AppRoot is a group at the root level of my application and domain model. Groups, which can be Organisations, Teams or Projects can be chained as children of either the AppRoot or in the order Organisations having teams, teams having projects.

There are also UserProjects which exist as associations of the AppRoot.

I needed a count of all the members in each project, and the child projects in each project, which is what the Map Reduce function does below using the Domain Model object GroupAssociation.

See the linked Domain Model diagram above for more detail :

```
public class All_Groups : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<All_Groups.Result>
{
    public class Result
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string GroupType { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public int GroupMemberCount { get; set; }
        public int TeamProjectCount { get; set; }
        public int OrganisationTeamCount { get; set; }
        public int AppRootOrganisationCount { get; set; }
        public int AppRootUserProjectCount { get; set; }
        public int AppRootTeamCount { get; set; }
        public int AppRootProjectCount { get; set; }
        public Group Group { get { return AppRoot ?? Organisation ?? Team ?? Project ?? UserProject ?? (Group)null; } }
        public AppRoot AppRoot { get; set; }
        public Organisation Organisation { get; set; }
        public Team Team { get; set; }
        public Project Project { get; set; }
        public UserProject UserProject { get; set; }
    }

    public All_Groups()
    {
        AddMap<AppRoot>(appRoots => from appRoot in appRoots
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        Type = "group",
                                        GroupType = "approot",
                                        appRoot.Id,
                                        GroupMemberCount = 0,
                                        TeamProjectCount = 0,
                                        OrganisationTeamCount = 0,
                                        AppRootOrganisationCount = 0,
                                        AppRootUserProjectCount = 0,
                                        AppRootTeamCount = 0,
                                        AppRootProjectCount = 0
                                    });

        AddMap<Organisation>(organisations => from organisation in organisations
                                              select new
                                                    {
                                                        Type = "group",
                                                        GroupType = "organisation",
                                                        organisation.Id,
                                                        GroupMemberCount = 0,
                                                        TeamProjectCount = 0,
                                                        OrganisationTeamCount = 0,
                                                        AppRootOrganisationCount = 0,
                                                        AppRootUserProjectCount = 0,
                                                        AppRootTeamCount = 0,
                                                        AppRootProjectCount = 0
                                                    });

        AddMap<Team>(teams => from team in teams
                              select new
                              {
                                  Type = "group",
                                  GroupType = "team",
                                  team.Id,
                                  GroupMemberCount = 0,
                                  TeamProjectCount = 0,
                                  OrganisationTeamCount = 0,
                                  AppRootOrganisationCount = 0,
                                  AppRootUserProjectCount = 0,
                                  AppRootTeamCount = 0,
                                  AppRootProjectCount = 0
                              });

        AddMap<Project>(projects => from project in projects
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        Type = "group",
                                        GroupType = "project",
                                        project.Id,
                                        GroupMemberCount = 0,
                                        TeamProjectCount = 0,
                                        OrganisationTeamCount = 0,
                                        AppRootOrganisationCount = 0,
                                        AppRootUserProjectCount = 0,
                                        AppRootTeamCount = 0,
                                        AppRootProjectCount = 0
                                    });

        AddMap<UserProject>(userProjects => from userProject in userProjects
                                            select new
                                            {
                                                Type = "group",
                                                GroupType = "userproject",
                                                userProject.Id,
                                                GroupMemberCount = 0,
                                                TeamProjectCount = 0,
                                                OrganisationTeamCount = 0,
                                                AppRootOrganisationCount = 0,
                                                AppRootUserProjectCount = 0,
                                                AppRootTeamCount = 0,
                                                AppRootProjectCount = 0
                                            });

        AddMap<GroupAssociation>(groupAssociations => from groupAssociation in groupAssociations
                                                      select new
                                                      {
                                                          Type = "groupassociation",
                                                          GroupType = (string)null,
                                                          Id = groupAssociation.ParentGroupId,
                                                          GroupMemberCount = 0,
                                                          TeamProjectCount = groupAssociation.ParentGroupType == "team" && groupAssociation.ChildGroupType == "project" ? 1 : 0,
                                                          OrganisationTeamCount = groupAssociation.ParentGroupType == "organisation" && groupAssociation.ChildGroupType == "team" ? 1 : 0,
                                                          AppRootOrganisationCount = groupAssociation.ParentGroupType == "approot" && groupAssociation.ChildGroupType == "organisation" ? 1 : 0,
                                                          AppRootUserProjectCount = groupAssociation.ParentGroupType == "approot" && groupAssociation.ChildGroupType == "userproject" ? 1 : 0,
                                                          AppRootTeamCount = groupAssociation.ParentGroupType == "approot" && groupAssociation.ChildGroupType == "team" ? 1 : 0,
                                                          AppRootProjectCount = groupAssociation.ParentGroupType == "approot" && groupAssociation.ChildGroupType == "project" ? 1 : 0
                                                      });

        AddMap<Member>(members => from member in members
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      Type = "member",
                                      GroupType = (string)null,
                                      member.Group.Id,
                                      GroupMemberCount = 1,
                                      TeamProjectCount = 0,
                                      OrganisationTeamCount = 0,
                                      AppRootOrganisationCount = 0,
                                      AppRootUserProjectCount = 0,
                                      AppRootTeamCount = 0,
                                      AppRootProjectCount = 0
                                  });

        Reduce = results => from result in results
                            group result by result.Id
                                into g
                                select new
                                {
                                    Type = g.Select(x => x.Type).FirstOrDefault(),
                                    GroupType = g.Select(x => x.GroupType).FirstOrDefault(),
                                    Id = g.Key,
                                    GroupMemberCount = g.Sum(x => x.GroupMemberCount),
                                    TeamProjectCount = g.Sum(x => x.TeamProjectCount),
                                    OrganisationTeamCount = g.Sum(x => x.OrganisationTeamCount),
                                    AppRootOrganisationCount = g.Sum(x => x.AppRootOrganisationCount),
                                    AppRootUserProjectCount = g.Sum(x => x.AppRootUserProjectCount),
                                    AppRootTeamCount = g.Sum(x => x.AppRootTeamCount),
                                    AppRootProjectCount = g.Sum(x => x.AppRootProjectCount)
                                };

        TransformResults = (database, results) =>
            from result in results
            let appRoot = database.Load<AppRoot>(result.Id)
            let organisation = database.Load<Organisation>(result.Id)
            let team = database.Load<Team>(result.Id)
            let project = database.Load<Project>(result.Id)
            let userProject = database.Load<UserProject>(result.Id)
            select new
            {
                result.Type,
                result.GroupType,
                result.Id,
                result.GroupMemberCount,
                result.TeamProjectCount,
                result.OrganisationTeamCount,
                result.AppRootOrganisationCount,
                result.AppRootUserProjectCount,
                result.AppRootTeamCount,
                result.AppRootProjectCount,
                AppRoot = appRoot,
                Organisation = organisation,
                Team = team,
                Project = project,
                UserProject = userProject
            };

        Store(x => x.Type, FieldStorage.Yes);
        Store(x => x.GroupType, FieldStorage.Yes);
        Store(x => x.Id, FieldStorage.Yes);
        Store(x => x.GroupMemberCount, FieldStorage.Yes);
        Store(x => x.TeamProjectCount, FieldStorage.Yes);
        Store(x => x.OrganisationTeamCount, FieldStorage.Yes);
        Store(x => x.AppRootOrganisationCount, FieldStorage.Yes);
        Store(x => x.AppRootUserProjectCount, FieldStorage.Yes);
        Store(x => x.AppRootTeamCount, FieldStorage.Yes);
        Store(x => x.AppRootProjectCount, FieldStorage.Yes);
    }
}
```

Here, because the model is quite linearly structured, it is possible to calculate all relationships between groups and memberships of groups because groups can have parents and children, but only of one type.

This may or may not help anyone out there trying to do a complicated Map/Reduce but the lesson I have learned on this one is to make sure that aggregation is possible at each step using a pragmatic approach.